# Метод PUT в форме html

Tags: php, html, laravel, bootstrap

Есть страница, сверстанная на bootstrap'е. На ней есть форма для редактирования пользователя, но при нажатии на кнопку "Сохранить" возникает ошибка без сообщения (MethodNotAllowedHttpException, No message), в чём проблема?
Моя форма:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="PUT" action="{{ route('users.updateuser', $user->id) }}">
  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">{{__('Edit Profile')}}</h1>
  <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ $user->name }}" placeholder="Имя" required autofocus>

  @if ($errors->has('name'))
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
      </span>
  @endif

  <input id="fam" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('fam') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="fam" value="{{ $user->fam }}" placeholder="Фамилия" required autofocus>

  @if ($errors->has('fam'))
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('fam') }}</strong>
      </span>
  @endif

  <input id="patr" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('patr') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="patr" value="{{ $user->patr }}" placeholder="Отчество">

  @if ($errors->has('patr'))
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('patr') }}</strong>
      </span>
  @endif

  <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}" disabled placeholder="Адрес эл. почты" required>

  @if ($errors->has('email'))
      <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
      </span>
  @endif
  <a href="{{route('login')}}" >{{__('Change password')}}</a>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">{{__('Save')}}</button>
  <a href="{{route('login')}}" style="color: red;">{{__('Delete account')}}</a>
  <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; Колганов Сергей, 2019</p>
  <input id="gender_id" type="hidden" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('gender_id') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="gender_id" value="{{ '3' }}" required autofocus>
  <input id="role_id" type="hidden" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('role_id') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="role_id" value="{{ '6778' }}" required autofocus>
  <input id="userstat_id" type="hidden" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('userstat_id') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="userstat_id" value="{{ '1' }}" required autofocus>
</form>
```

Маршрут:

```
Route::put('users/{user}/updateuser', 'StationController@updateuser')
      ->name('users.updateuser');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для реализации `CRUD` приложения в `Laravel` можно сделать такой роутинг:

```
Route::resource('tasks', 'TaskController');
```

Или в [ручную](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing):

```
Route::put('tasks', function()
    {

    });
```

В `html`:

```
<form action="{{ route('route_name') }}" method="post">
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Или так:

```
<form action="{{ route('route_name') }}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

А ещё ответ есть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143674/laravel-form-html-with-put-method-for-put-routes) .

Answer (score 0):

В соответствии со стандартами `method` у формы может быть только `get`, `post` или `dialog` [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-method)

Соответственно браузер отправляет `post` вместо `put`, а соответствующего маршрута у вас нет

Лучше добавьте `$user->id` в качестве hidden input в саму форму и отправьте post

Comment: Как изменить маршрут мой, кроме того, что я передаю методом post, а не put? Браузер теперь ругается на то, что у меня отсутствует параметр для маршрута с URI: URI: users/{user}/updateuser

Comment: Можно с `html` отправить `POST`, а на сервере выполнить `PUT`. http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.put-method.php

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один способ решения нашёлся: создать форму через blade шаблон, думаю так проще :)

```
    {{
    Form::model($user, ['class' => 'form-signin',
        'method' => 'PUT',
        'route'  => [
            'users.updateuser',
            $user->id,
        ]
    ])
}}

  {{
      Form::submit(
          __('Save'),
          [
              'class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block',
          ]
      )
  }}  {{Form::close()}}
```